# Is it possible to express Gibbs free energy as following?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

We know $$\Delta G =\Delta H -T\Delta S$$
$$\Delta S= \frac{Q_{rev}}{T} $$
Hence $$\Delta G=\Delta H-Q_{rev} $$

Comment: Yes... It is possible. But a better question for me to ask is: why would you not think it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only if the temperature T in the initial and final equilibrium states of the system is the same *and* you are able to identify a reversible path between the initial and final equilibrium states over which all the heat transfer takes place at the temperature T.